# C# SSRS 'ReportExecutionService' does not contain a definition for 'ListChildren'

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to get a list of folders and RDL files in those folders on an SSRS 2008 server and I'm getting the following messages when trying to iterate through the folders.

'ReportExecutionService' does not contain a definition for 'ListChildren' and no accessible extension method 'ListChildren' accepting a first argument of type 'ReportExecutionService' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
        var rs05 = new SSRS2005.ReportExecutionService();
        rs05.Url = "http://<servername>/ReportServer/ReportService2005.asmx?wsdl";
        rs05.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        var reports = rs05.ListChildren("/");
```

I have it exactly as every example out there. Is ListChildren not exposed? Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you put in the server name? <servername>    If you are using 2008 then change name from 2005 to 2008.  Examples used different version of Reporting Service then you have installed.

Comment: I did put in the server name, but I don't want to include it here for security reasons. When I use 2008 then I get
  
"The path of the item 'wsdl' is not valid. The full path must be less than 260 characters long; other restrictions apply. If the report server is in native mode, the path must start with slash. (rsInvalidItemPath)"

Comment: the folder ReportServer should be a shared folder on the Server.  You should be able to use a windows explorer to see the name of the files and folders in the directory.  I was assuming that you were using SSRS 2008 that everything would be referencing 2008.  I'm not sure if you would need to upgrade the file from 2005 to 2008.  Before running in c# I would try to use the report view in the server to see if it still runs under 2008.  SSRS will give much better error messages than c#.

Comment: According to the docs its the ReportingService2005 class which has that method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005?view=sqlserver-2016 not the ReportExecutionService class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice?view=sqlserver-2016